# What part of speech is the word "smiling" in this example?

Tags: grammar

The present participial (participle) is formed from the verb stem normally by adding *-ing* to the infinitive with some variation based on the final letters of the stem. Thus *to smile* becomes *smiling*. The participle can act as a nonfinite verb, adjective, noun, or as part of an adverb clause. [*The Chicago Manual of Style*]

Some examples:

*Smiling is good for you.* - Noun [Gerund]

*I love to see your smiling face.* - Adjective

*Joe ran from Melissa, smiling as he went.* - Nonfinite verb [Joe was smiling]

*She was grinning, smiling even, as she walked up to the podium.* - Participle phrase being used as an adverb

But what about:

**I said, "Look at those two smiling over there!"**?

Comment: "Look at those two (who are) smiling over there." Whiz-deletion. Part of speech - Adjective (post-positive)

Comment: @Rathony Agreed about the whiz deletion (potentially), but not about the adjective!

Comment: @Araucaria I am old -school.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see "smiling" differently in your examples:

1. *Smiling is good for you*: verb interpretation preferred (cf. "To smile is good for you"), but noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional smiling")
2. *I love to see your smiling face*: verb pre-modifying the noun “face”.
3. *Joe ran from Melissa, smiling as he went*: verb heading the clause "Smiling as he went" as predicative adjunct with "Joe" as predicand.
4. *She was grinning, smiling even as she went …*: verb (coordinated), part of present progressive aspect.

And your question: *Look at those two smiling over there*: verb as head of subordinate clause "smiling over there", modifying the NP "two".

Comment: Thankfully, I agree with your solution. However {1} *smiling* is the subject of the sentence, {2} you're totally right; my bad for pulling examples out of my arse, {3} shoulder shrug, and {4} perhaps you missed the second comma after *even*? It seems to me that the two-word phrase modifies *grinning*, but I see your point.

Comment: @Stu W Yes, "smiling" is indeed the subject in 1. Non-finite clauses often appear as subjects, as in _**Bringing your dad** was a great idea_. In your example, the clause happens to be the single word "smiling", but it's a clause nonetheless. Same with examples like _**Smoking** is forbidden_.

Comment: =1 An hour or so ago. I added my own answer to highlight the need to keep form and function separate in our analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking it apart will be helpful here.

First, there's an implied subject in this imperative construction: "[You] Look at those two smiling over there"

1. [You] = subject
2. Look = verb
3. At those two smiling over there = prepositional phrase, functioning as a adverb modifying "look."

Going further with our object,

3.1. At those two smiling = prepositional phrase

3.2. over there = prepositional phrase, function as an adj modifying "those two"

> Within 3.1, we also see that "those two smiling" is the object of the preposition "at."

Thus, "smiling" modifies the noun phrase "those two," and should be taken as an **adjective.**

Comment: I agree with your conclusion. But technically *at...* is not an object: (direct) objects don't start with a preposition.

Comment: I agree with @Cerberus. Why not edit your post?

Comment: Learn something everyday; will do!

Comment: Yes, but even if  "smiling" were an adjective, it could only premodify a noun (cf. _a smiling man_ but not *_a man smiling_) so it can't be an adjective here, only a verb, cf. _those two smiling sweetly over there_, with "sweetly" as adverbial modifier.

Comment: @BillJ, I think you've got some ground to stand on here. Upon review, it seems to me that "smiling" functions as a part of a "reduced relative clause." This clause has an implied relative adverb and linking verb; i.e., "those two [who are] smiling over there." In this clause, "smiling" does, indeed, serve as verb, with the auxiliary "are" attached to it ; however, the entire clause functions as an adjective modifying "those two." So .... I guess we're both right

Comment: @BillJ: But that isn't necessarily contradictory. Participles are essential both adjectives and verbs at the same time: adjectives externally and verbs internally. The reason Arcadian mentioned *adjective* here was not to emphasise how it was adjectival rather than verbal, but rather that it was adjectival rather than substantival (noun-ish). And he was right about that.

Comment: @Cerberus There's a connection, of course, but we have to distinguish verb and adjective uses, e.g. In _He's entertaining the audience_ "entertaining" is clearly a verb, but in _The show was entertaining_, it's an adjective

Comment: @Cerberus But that's just to confuse the function with the form. Modifying a noun is a function. It happens to be one that can also be done by an adjective. But calling a verb modifying a noun an 'adjective' is not ok. Most  electricians are men, but saying that Sarah is a man because she does a job often done by men is just flat incorrect.

Comment: @BillJ: I recognise the difference between those two constructions, but I find "verb v. adjective" far too blunt, because the word retains aspects of both verb and adjective in both sentences. The terms suggest a strict dichotomy, but it is in my opinion essential to recognise the dual nature of participles and gerunds (and infinitives, for that matter, though less so).

Comment: @Araucaria: No, both have to do with function. *Those senators supporting Caesar left the room*: internally, *supporting* is mostly a verb, because it has a typically verbal dependent constituent, an object. Externally, it modifies *senators*, and it is typical of adjectives to modify nouns. It's a hybrid word. ...

Comment: ... Certain essential semantico-syntactic properties of participles remain the same even when used as in *the supporting senators left the room* v. *the senators were supporting Caesar*: the word can still be said to pertain to a specific noun in both sentences (*the senators*); and it still has more or less the same "predicate frame", in that the noun it modifies can be said to be its agent. This last point can be seen even more clearly in "adjectival" constructions such as *the Caesar-supporting senators*, ungainly though this one may be, where the verbal object can be added back in.

Comment: @Cerberus So you've basically done exactly the Susan being  a man thing with your analysis. In addition you say that externally it's an adjective, but it has a Direct Object *Ceasar*. Only verbs have Direct Objects.

Comment: @Araucaria: I chanced upon this old tab that I had open. I'd still appreciate it if you found the time to reply directly to what I said in the last two of my comment, but of course I will understand if you don't have the energy/time/motivation to do so. Verb-like things depend on a participle, making it a verb "internally". It depends on things that typically take an adjective, so that makes it adjective-like "externally" (see my examples about the *supporting senators*). What is wrong with that (widely held) analysis?

Answer (score 3):

It's important to keep the grammatical relations (or syntactic functions) separate from the parts of speech.

> 1. Smiling is good for you.
> 2. I love to see your smiling face
> 3. Joe ran from Melissa, smiling as he went.
> 4. She was grinning, smiling even, as she walked up to the podium.
> 5. Look at those two smiling over there!

The probable reading is that *smiling* is a gerund-participle verb in each example in 1-5 above. However, the grammatical relations in each sentence are different. In those sentences where the grammatical relations are those we associate with nouns, traditional grammar would call them *gerunds*. In all other instances, where they head clauses functioning as Modifiers of some description, traditional grammar calls them *participles*. In many modern grammars they are just recognised as the *-ing* forms of verbs which can do different jobs in a sentence or phrase. We call these *gerund-participles*. They head *gerund-participle clauses*. I'll call these clauses GP's for short

In (1) the GP is Subject of the sentence. In (2) the GP is the modifier of a noun (the same kind of job that adjectives and nouns can both do as well). In (3) it is an Adjunct, more specifically a Predicative Adjunct describing the Subject, *Joe*. In (4) the GP is part of a co-ordination (it means something similar to the coordination in *she was [grinning and  smiling]*) which is functioning as Complement of the verb *BE*. In (5) the GP is post-modifying the word *two*, in the same way that an adjective phrase or relative clause might.

Remember that even though many of these functions (*Subject*, *Modifier* and so on) are functions that may be done by noun phrases or adjectives, this does not make the verbs doing these jobs nouns or adjectives. They are verbs! Specifically, they are gerund-participle forms of the verb.